# Vue 3 CSS files overlapping on component switch

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I've imported some CSS files with

```
<style scoped>@import "../assets/XYZ.css";</style>
```

in different components. Now whenever I switch components the CSS from the other component is loading as well. Let's say I switch from Home.Vue to Blog.Vue, then Home.Vue's CSS file will be imported into Blog.Vue too. Whenever I refresh, everything seems to be fixed. Adding scoped doesn't seem to work for me.

I am using **vue-router** to switch between components.

This is my relevant code:

main.js

```
import './assets/main.css';
```

^ This is a css file to be used across my website on every component

Home.Vue

```
<style scoped>@import "../assets/home.css";</style>
```

Blog.Vue

```
<style scoped>@import "../assets/blog.css";</style>
```

Comment: Does it work if you write the imported CSS file directly into the `style` tag? What's the content of those CSS files, especially the selectors?

Comment: @kissu  , Well yes that seems to work, except now my body { } CSS tag is not working anymore, but that probably has to do with the style being 'scoped' (?). The content in the CSS files are bascially just changing the body (bg color) and changing the main's bg color.

Comment: Scoped it to say that the style will only be applied to the current `.vue` file. If you thing is changing the background, it may be interesting to update it via some [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).